# Unordered Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm trying to learn Linked List, but I encountered a problem.

below is the code for linkedlist.h file

```
#ifndef H_LinkedListType
#define H_LinkedListType
   
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
 
using namespace std;

//Definition of the node

template <class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template <class Type>
class linkedListIterator
{
public:
   linkedListIterator();
     //Default constructor
     //Postcondition: current = nullptr;

   linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr);
     //Constructor with a parameter.
     //Postcondition: current = ptr;

   Type operator*();
     //Function to overload the dereferencing operator *.
     //Postcondition: Returns the info contained in the node.

   linkedListIterator<Type> operator++();    
     //Overload the pre-increment operator.
     //Postcondition: The iterator is advanced to the next 
     //               node.

   bool operator==(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const; 
     //Overload the equality operator.
     //Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is equal to 
     //               the iterator specified by right, 
     //               otherwise it returns the value false.

   bool operator!=(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const; 
     //Overload the not equal to operator.
     //Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is not  
     //               equal to the iterator specified by  
     //               right; otherwise it returns the value 
     //               false.

private:
   nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to point to the current 
                            //node in the linked list
};

template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type>::linkedListIterator()
{
    current = nullptr;
}

template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type>::
                  linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr)
{
    current = ptr;
}

template <class Type>
Type linkedListIterator<Type>::operator*()
{
    return current->info;
}

template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListIterator<Type>::
                                  operator++()   
{
    current = current->link;

    return *this;
}

template <class Type>
bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator==
               (const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
{
    return (current == right.current);
}

template <class Type>
bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator!=
                 (const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
{    return (current != right.current);
}


//*****************  class linkedListType   ****************

template <class Type>
class linkedListType
{
public:
    const linkedListType<Type>& operator=
                         (const linkedListType<Type>&);  
      //Overload the assignment operator.

    void initializeList(); 
      //Initialize the list to an empty state.
      //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr, 
      //               count = 0;

    bool isEmptyList() const;
      //Function to determine whether the list is empty. 
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty,
      //               otherwise it returns false.

    void print() const;
      //Function to output the data contained in each node.
      //Postcondition: none

    int length() const;
      //Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
      //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.

    void destroyList();
      //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
      //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr, 
      //               count = 0;

    Type front() const; 
      //Function to return the first element of the list.
      //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be 
      //              empty.
      //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
      //               terminates; otherwise, the first 
      //               element of the list is returned.

    Type back() const; 
      //Function to return the last element of the list.
      //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be 
      //              empty.
      //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
      //               terminates; otherwise, the last  
      //               element of the list is returned.

    virtual bool search(const Type& searchItem) const = 0;
      //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the 
      //               list, otherwise the value false is 
      //               returned.

    virtual void insertFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;
      //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
      //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
      //               inserted at the beginning of the list,
      //               last points to the last node in the list, 
      //               and count is incremented by 1.

    virtual void insertLast(const Type& newItem) = 0;
      //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
      //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem 
      //               is inserted at the end of the list,
      //               last points to the last node in the 
      //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

    virtual void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem) = 0;
      //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
      //Postcondition: If found, the node containing 
      //               deleteItem is deleted from the list.
      //               first points to the first node, last
      //               points to the last node of the updated 
      //               list, and count is decremented by 1.

    linkedListIterator<Type> begin();
      //Function to return an iterator at the begining of 
      //the linked list.
      //Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current
      //               is set to first.

    linkedListIterator<Type> end();
      //Function to return an iterator one element past the 
      //last element of the linked list. 
      //Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current 
      //               is set to nullptr.

    linkedListType(); 
      //Default constructor
      //Initializes the list to an empty state.
      //Postcondition: first = nullptr, last = nullptr, 
      //               count = 0; 

    linkedListType(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList); 
      //copy constructor

    ~linkedListType();   
      //Destructor
      //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
      //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed. 

protected:
    int count;   //variable to store the number of 
                 //elements in the list
    nodeType<Type> *first; //pointer to the first node of the list
    nodeType<Type> *last;  //pointer to the last node of the list

private: 
    void copyList(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList); 
      //Function to make a copy of otherList.
      //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and
      //               assigned to this list.
};


template <class Type>
bool linkedListType<Type>::isEmptyList() const
{
    return (first == nullptr);
}

template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType() //default constructor
{
    first = nullptr;
    last = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}

template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::destroyList()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;   //pointer to deallocate the memory
                            //occupied by the node
    while (first != nullptr)   //while there are nodes in 
    {                          //the list
        temp = first;        //set temp to the current node
        first = first->link; //advance first to the next node
        delete temp;   //deallocate the memory occupied by temp
    }
    last = nullptr; //initialize last to nullptr; first has 
               //already been set to nullptr by the while loop
    count = 0;
}

template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::initializeList()
{
    destroyList(); //if the list has any nodes, delete them
}

template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::print() const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;    //set current so that it points to 
                        //the first node
    while (current != nullptr) //while more data to print
    {
        cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->link;
    }
}//end print

template <class Type>
int linkedListType<Type>::length() const
{
    return count;
}  //end length

template <class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::front() const
{   
    assert(first != nullptr);

    return first->info; //return the info of the first node 
}//end front

template <class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::back() const
{   
    assert(last != nullptr);

    return last->info; //return the info of the last node   
}//end back

template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::begin()
{
    linkedListIterator<Type> temp(first);

    return temp;
}

template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::end()
{
    linkedListIterator<Type> temp(nullptr);

    return temp;
}

template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::copyList
                   (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList) 
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create a node
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    if (first != nullptr) //if the list is nonempty, make it empty
       destroyList();

    if (otherList.first == nullptr) //otherList is empty
    {
        first = nullptr;
        last = nullptr;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        current = otherList.first; //current points to the 
                                   //list to be copied
        count = otherList.count;

            //copy the first node
        first = new nodeType<Type>;  //create the node

        first->info = current->info; //copy the info
        first->link = nullptr;        //set the link field of 
                                   //the node to nullptr
        last = first;              //make last point to the
                                   //first node
        current = current->link;     //make current point to
                                     //the next node

           //copy the remaining list
        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;  //create a node
            newNode->info = current->info; //copy the info
            newNode->link = nullptr;       //set the link of 
                                        //newNode to nullptr
            last->link = newNode;  //attach newNode after last
            last = newNode;        //make last point to
                                   //the actual last node
            current = current->link;   //make current point 
                                       //to the next node
        }//end while
    }//end else
}//end copyList

template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::~linkedListType() //destructor
{
   destroyList();
}//end destructor

template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType
                      (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
{
    first = nullptr;
    copyList(otherList);
}//end copy constructor

         //overload the assignment operator
template <class Type>
const linkedListType<Type>& linkedListType<Type>::operator=
                      (const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
{ 
    if (this != &otherList) //avoid self-copy
    {
        copyList(otherList);
    }//end else

     return *this; 
}

#endif
```

Below is the code for the testProgLinkedList.cpp

```
//This program tests various operation of a linked list
//34 62 21 90 66 53 88 24 10 -999 
  
#include <iostream>                                 //Line 1
#include "unorderedLinkedList.h"                    //Line 2

using namespace std;                                //Line 3

int main()                                          //Line 4
{                                                   //Line 5
    unorderedLinkedList<int> list1, list2;          //Line 6
    int num;                                        //Line 7

    cout << "Line 8: Enter integers ending " 
         << "with -999" << endl;                    //Line 8
    cin >> num;                                     //Line 9

    while (num != -999)                             //Line 10
    {                                               //Line 11
        list1.insertLast(num);                      //Line 12
        cin >> num;                                 //Line 13
    }                                               //Line 14

    cout << endl;                                   //Line 15

    cout << "Line 16: list1: ";                     //Line 16
    list1.print();                                  //Line 17
    cout << endl;                                   //Line 18
    cout << "Line 19: Length of list1: " 
         << list1.length() << endl;                 //Line 19

    list2 = list1;     //test the assignment operator Line 20

    cout << "Line 21: list2: ";                     //Line 21
    list2.print();                                  //Line 22
    cout << endl;                                   //Line 23
    cout << "Line 24: Length of list2: " 
         << list2.length() << endl;                 //Line 24

    cout << "Line 25: Enter the number to be "
         << "deleted: ";                            //Line 25
    cin >> num;                                     //Line 26
    cout << endl;                                   //Line 27

    list2.deleteNode(num);                          //Line 28
    
    cout << "Line 29: After deleting " << num 
         << " list2: " << endl;                     //Line 29
    list2.print();                                  //Line 30
    cout << endl;                                   //Line 31

    cout << "Line 32: Length of list2: " 
         << list2.length() << endl;                 //Line 32

    cout << endl << "Line 33: Output list1 " 
         << "using an iterator" << endl;            //Line 33

    linkedListIterator<int> it;                     //Line 34

    for (it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); 
                             ++it)                  //Line 35
        cout << *it << " ";                         //Line 36
    cout << endl;                                   //Line 37

    return 0;                                       //Line 38
}                                                   //Line 39
```

Below is the code for the unorderedLinkList.h file

```
    #ifndef H_UnorderedLinkedList
    #define H_UnorderedLinkedList

    #include "linkedList.h"

    using namespace std;

    template <class Type>
    class unorderedLinkedList: public linkedListType<Type>
    {
    public:
        bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;
          //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
          //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the
          //               list, otherwise the value false is
          //               returned.

        void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
          //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
          //               inserted at the beginning of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the
          //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

        void insertLast(const Type& newItem);
          //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
          //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem
          //               is inserted at the end of the list,
          //               last points to the last node in the
          //               list, and count is incremented by 1.

        void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
          //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
          //Postcondition: If found, the node containing
          //               deleteItem is deleted from the list.
          //               first points to the first node, last
          //               points to the last node of the updated
          //               list, and count is decremented by 1.
    };


    template <class Type>
    bool unorderedLinkedList<Type>::
                       search(const Type& searchItem) const
    {
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        bool found = false;

        current = first; //set current to point to the first
                         //node in the list

        while (current != nullptr    && !found)    //search the list
            if (current->info == searchItem) //searchItem is found
                found = true;
            else
                current = current->link; //make current point to
                                         //the next node
        return found;
    }//end search

    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

        newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

        newNode->info = newItem;    //store the new item in the node
        newNode->link = first;      //insert newNode before first
        first = newNode;            //make first point to the
                                    //actual first node
        count++;                    //increment count

        if (last == nullptr)   //if the list was empty, newNode is also
                            //the last node in the list
            last = newNode;
    }//end insertFirst

    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

        newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

        newNode->info = newItem;  //store the new item in the node
        newNode->link = nullptr;     //set the link field of newNode
                                  //to nullptr

        if (first == nullptr)  //if the list is empty, newNode is
                            //both the first and last node
        {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            count++;        //increment count
        }
        else    //the list is not empty, insert newNode after last
        {
            last->link = newNode; //insert newNode after last
            last = newNode; //make last point to the actual
                            //last node in the list
            count++;        //increment count
        }
    }//end insertLast


    template <class Type>
    void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
    {
        nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
        nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
        bool found;

        if (first == nullptr)    //Case 1; the list is empty.
            cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list."
                 << endl;
        else
        {
            if (first->info == deleteItem) //Case 2
            {
                current = first;
                first = first->link;
                count--;
                if (first == nullptr)    //the list has only one node
                    last = nullptr;
                delete current;
            }
            else //search the list for the node with the given info
            {
                found = false;
                trailCurrent = first;  //set trailCurrent to point
                                       //to the first node
                current = first->link; //set current to point to
                                       //the second node

                while (current != nullptr && !found)
                {
                    if (current->info != deleteItem)
                    {
                        trailCurrent = current;
                        current = current-> link;
                    }
                    else
                        found = true;
                }//end while

                if (found) //Case 3; if found, delete the node
                {
                    trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                    count--;

                    if (last == current)   //node to be deleted
                                           //was the last node
                        last = trailCurrent; //update the value
                                             //of last
                    delete current;  //delete the node from the list
                }
                else
                    cout << "The item to be deleted is not in "
                         << "the list." << endl;
            }//end else
        }//end else
    }//end deleteNode


    #endif
```

But when I compiled the code it showed error messages as seen below:
I don't know how to fix the errors as I am new to coding. Please help me.

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI2YC.png)

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste all text *as text* into your questions. And if you get build errors, then please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can ignore all the errors after the first couple. Fix errors one at a time starting with the first.

This line

```
    current = first; //set current to point to the first
                     //node in the list
```

generates an error which says that the compiler doesn't know what `first` is. Now it looks like there is a declaration of `first` in `linkedListType<Type>` but the compiler doesn't find it. Why? Well that is complicated, but basically it is because your class is a template and the name is defined in a parent template class. Fortunately there is a simple fix, just add `this->`

```
    current = this->first; //set current to point to the first
                           //node in the list
```

More details [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates), but be warned it's complicated.